# How do I mask a URL in Apache while pulling data from another server?

Tags: php, apache, dns, subdomain, white-labelling

I have two URLs, **company.com** and **example.com**. They are both on different servers.

When I visit **company.com/page** I want to actually be loading the content from **page.example.com**.

Similarly, if I go to **company.com/page/about-us** I want the information to pull from **page.example.com/about-us** but is white-labelled under the company.com domain.

I have access to both servers and both domain hosting accounts, they are both Apache-based and the sites are built in PHP. What would be the easiest and/or fastest way to get this masking set up?

Comment: Consider using a Reverse-Proxy in apache, so that requests to company.com are forwarded to example.com and the example.com response goes back to company.com that gives the final answer to the end user. So end user never knows he gets any results from example.com, he only communicates with company.com